# AngularJS orderby / controller behavior: controller executed on orderby

Tags: angularjs, controller

I took a sample AngularJS app and began to change it to suit my needs.  Now clicking to change the orderby causes the entire controller to be reloaded.  Well that's where I'm initializing the default orderby.  So what I get when I click a new orderby is a flash of the proper orderby then a quick return to the default.  An alert showed me the controller is getting executed but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7maY9PjNlUGCYeZx3UXm?p=preview)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="promptsApp">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>    
    <script src="promptsService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('promptsApp', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/prompts',
    {
      controller: 'PromptsController',
      templateUrl: 'partial.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/prompts' });
});
```

controllers.js

```
app.controller('PromptsController', function ($scope, promptsService) 
{
  init();

  function init()
  {
    $scope.prompts = promptsService.getPrompts();
    $scope.orderby='TRANSFEREE';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    //alert('Hi');
  } 

  $scope.setOrder = function (orderby) {
    if (orderby === $scope.orderby)
    {
      $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }
    $scope.orderby = orderby;
  };
});
```

promptsService.js

```
app.service('promptsService', function () 
{
  this.getPrompts = function (user) 
  {
    var prompts = [
        {
            id: 1, NOTE: 'Call client about something', CALLBACK_DATE: '12-01-2013', TRANSFEREE: 'Tom Tuttle', REG_NUM: '123456'
        },
        {
            id: 2, NOTE: 'Notify client of delay', CALLBACK_DATE: '12-10-2013', TRANSFEREE: 'Eddie Munster', REG_NUM: '101314'
        },
        {
            id: 3, NOTE: 'Complete paperwork', CALLBACK_DATE: '12-12-2013', TRANSFEREE: 'Mary Tyler Moore', REG_NUM: '998877'
        }
        ];

    return prompts;
  };
});
```

partial.html

```
<div class="prompts">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
       <h3>Prompts</h3>
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
         <li ng-class="{'active': orderby=='CALLBACK_DATE'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setOrder('CALLBACK_DATE')">Date</a></li>
         <li ng-class="{'active': orderby=='TRANSFEREE'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setOrder('TRANSFEREE')">Transferee</a></li>
         <li> (Currently: {{orderby}})</li>
       </ul>
     </header>

     <div>
       <div class="row cardContainer">
         <div class="span3 card" data-ng-repeat="prompt in prompts | orderBy:orderby:reverse">
           <div class="cardHeader">{{prompt.TRANSFEREE}}</div>
           <div class="cardBody">{{prompt.NOTE}}
         <br># <a href="#">{{prompt.REG_NUM}}</a> {{prompt.CALLBACK_DATE}}
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    <br />
    {{prompts.length}} prompts
  </div>
</div>
```

See Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7maY9PjNlUGCYeZx3UXm?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-class="{'active': orderby=='CALLBACK_DATE'}">
    <a href="" ng-click="setOrder('CALLBACK_DATE')">\
        CallBack Date
    </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{'active': orderby=='TRANSFEREE'}">
    <a href="" ng-click="setOrder('TRANSFEREE')">
        Transferee
    </a>
</li>
<li>> Currently: {{orderby}}</li>
```

Remove the `href="#"` and replace it with `href=""` to get the desired result.
Having `href="#"` causes the route to change (and become the same as before) but triggers the initialization of the controller once more.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, been driving me nuts for 3 days.